# clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a'

Tags: react-native

My react-native app is compiling fine in ios simulator, but I am getting this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
        Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app/F8v2 normal x86_64

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a'
```

Longer Output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/*****/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/*****/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CodePush -L/Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React -F/Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/F8v2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/F8v2.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime /Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a /Users/******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a /Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTGeolocation.a /Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTImage.a /Users/******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a /Users/******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTNetwork.a /Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a /Users/******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTText.a /Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a /Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTWebSocket.a -lPods-F8v2 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/F8v2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/F8v2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app/F8v2
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/*******/f8app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a'

    ** BUILD FAILED **


    The following build commands failed:
        Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app/F8v2 normal x86_64
    (1 failure)
    Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app
    An error was encountered processing the command (domain=LaunchServicesError, code=0):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved in the following way:

1. On Xcode select the project > `Build Settings` > Set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `Yes`.
2. Repeat same for target.
3. Run.
4. Set `Build Active Architecture Only` back to `No` if you want your previous configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've had dealed with this error a lot. Whenever I thought I solved the issue I had it again following day. I didn't have any error on android side. I suggest before changing any options in xcode think about it twice. You can try following steps.

1-) Project -> Targets-> your project -> build phases -> link binary iwth libraries -> click add (+) -> add add libReact.a

2-) open projects erp.xcodeprof -> project.pbxproj and be sure that any third party libraries is not added more than one time.

3-) check your node_modules folder if there is any library folder which is not used on ios side delete it, build again and add the third party library again.

Good Luck